# Python Как написать тест. Подскажите направление

Tags: python, тестирование

Хочу вот такой соционический тест для тренировки на Python  сделать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Там 68 вопросов, каждый раз по выбору радиокнопки , попадаем на новые варианты. А в самом конце, когда на все вопросы ответил в зависимости от выбранных вариантов он показывает соционический тип и в зависимости от ответов уровень интоверсии- экставерсии, логики и этики итд. + описание тима.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ссылка на сам тест https://www.tests-tests.com/gulenko.php?qnum=1
Подскажите направление пожалуйста как это оптимальней всего сделать? Какую лучше использовать библиотеку? Использовать Django формы в связки с моделями или что-то другое? И самое главное. Есть ли сайт если я например захочу примеры таких проектов посмотреть у других людей ? Чтобы такие вопросы тут не спрашивать.GitHub вроде не подошёл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Накидал быстренько так. Потестил, вроде работает.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, HttpResponse

#   Переменная с вопросами и ответами/баллами
my_quests = {
    1:['Выберите любое число', ['Два', 0],['Семь', 1],['Восемь', 2]],
    2:['Выберите любой цвет', ['Красный', 0],['Желтый', 1],['Синий', 2]],
    3:['Выберите любое животное', ['Корова', 0],['Носорог', 1],['Жираф', 2]],
    4:['Выберите то, что нельзя выбрать', ['Можно выбрать', 0],['Нельзя выбрать', 1]],
    5:['Попробуйте ничего не выбрать', ['Выбрать', 0],['Не выбрать', 1]],
}

#   Отвечает за формирование элементов в форме
def render_form (number):
    HTML_='<input name="page" value="'+str(number)+'" hidden><h3>'+my_quests[number][0]+'</h3>'
    for row in my_quests[number][1:len(my_quests[number])]:
        HTML_+='<p>'+row[0]+' <input name="result" value="'+str(row[1])+'" type="radio"></p>'
    return HTML_

#   Основной обработчик
def index(request):
    data={'form_':''}
    #   Если в сессии нет нужных переменных, то создаем
    if 'quest' not in request.session:
        request.session['quest']={}
        request.session['result'] = 0
        index = 1
        for row in my_quests:
            request.session['quest'][index]=None
            index +=1
        request.session.modified = True

    #   Если нам пришел ответ, то считаем его
    if 'result' in request.GET:
        request.session['result'] += int (request.GET['result'])
        request.session['quest'][request.GET['page']] = 'Done'
        request.session.modified = True
        print (request.session['quest'])

    if 'page' not in request.GET:
        return redirect ('/test/?page=1')
    else:
        #   Если был получен ответ на этот вопрос, то идем дальше
        if request.session['quest'][request.GET['page']] != None:
            next_page = int(request.GET['page'])+1
            #   Если на все вопросы даны ответы, то возвращаем результат
            if next_page-1>=len(my_quests):
                return HttpResponse ('Вы завершили тестирование и набрали '+str(request.session['result'])+' баллов!')
            return redirect ('/test/?page='+ str(next_page))
        else:
            #   Рендерим форму
            data['form_']=render_form (int(request.GET['page']))
    return render (request, 'index.html', data)
```

Файлик с шаблоном index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Тестирование</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="GET">
            <p>{{ form_|safe }}</p>
            <p><button>Ответить</button></p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Естественно, вопросов может быть больше, количество ответом больше/меньше, а на строке return HttpResponse ('Вы завершили тестирование... рекомендую добавить функцию, которая по количеству набранных баллов будет возвращать результат.

ЗЫ: Код постарался сделать максимально гибким, чтобы править пришлось только переменную my_quests

Comment: Спасибо, Вы какой-то гений)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант использовать Django, да. В этом случае вижу реализацию так:

1. Пользователь заходит на сайт и получает сессию. В нее положим словарь из 68 пустых ячеек, пронумеровав каждую для конкретного вопроса.
2. Создадим словарь так же под каждый вопрос, но в словарь поместим кортеж в виде ответ/количество баллов.
3. В шаблоне сделаем простенькую форму с общими элементами управления.
4. После выбора какого-то значения в форме и жмак по кнопке будет отправлять в Django GET-запросы с номером ответа (или кол-ом баллов за него). Сама же форма будет формироваться из словаря с вопросами/баллами.
5. Теперь со стороны сервера в сессионную переменную (ранее созданный список) добавляем кол-во баллов и перемещаем на следующий не отвеченный вопрос.
6. Когда на все вопросы получены ответы необходимо по какой-то формуле (тут уже сами, исходя из вопросов) просчитать и по полученному значению вернуть какой-то результат.

Естественно, все это тезисно. Бонусом можно докидать всякие элементы по типу "Сохранить результат", "Поделиться", "Пройти еще раз", но это уже вкусовщина.

Comment: Когда я говорил про систему баллов, то имел ввиду нечто похожее https://prof-dialog.ru/manual/diagnostic-criterion-1-reliability

Comment: Спасибо большое, а то я ищу как тесты делать на Python и Джанго , а мне выдаётся Unit Testing